# Run infinite while loop in Python module

Tags: python, while-loop, module

I'm writing a Python module to read jstest output and make Xbox gamepad working in Python on Linux. I need to start in background infinite while loop in __init__ on another thread that looks like this:

```py
import os
from threading import Thread
import time
import select
import subprocess


class Joystick:
    """Initializes base class and launches jstest and xboxdrv"""
    def __init__(self, refreshRate=2000, deadzone=4000):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(['xboxdrv', '-D', '-v', '--detach-kernel-driver', '--dpad-as-button'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
        self.pipe = self.proc.stdout
        self.refresh = refreshRate
        self.refreshDelay = 1.0 / refreshRate
        self.refreshTime = 0  # indicates the next refresh
        self.deadzone = deadzone
        self.start()
        self.xbox = subprocess.Popen(['jstest', '--normal', '/dev/input/js0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1, universal_newlines=True)
        self.response = self.xbox.stdout.readline()
        a = Thread(target=self.reload2())
        a.start()
        print("working")

    def reload2(self):
        while True:
            self.response = self.xbox.stdout.readline()
            print("read")
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def start(self):
        global leftVibrateAmount, rightVibrateAmount
        leftVibrateAmount = 0
        rightVibrateAmount = 0
        readTime = time.time() + 1  # here we wait a while
        found = False
        while readTime > time.time() and not found:
            readable, writeable, exception = select.select([self.pipe], [], [], 0)
            if readable:
                response = self.pipe.readline()
                # tries to detect if controller is connected
                if response == b'[ERROR] XboxdrvDaemon::run(): fatal exception: DBusSubsystem::request_name(): failed to become primary owner of dbus name\n':
                    raise IOError("Another instance of xboxdrv is running.")
                elif response == b'[INFO]  XboxdrvDaemon::connect(): connecting slot to thread\n':
                    found = True
                    self.reading = response
                elif response == b'':
                    raise IOError('Are you running as sudo?')
        if not found:
            self.pipe.close()
            # halt if controller not found
            raise IOError("Xbox controller/receiver isn't connected")
```

The loop is defined to start running in __init__ function like so:

```py
a = threading.Thread(target=self.reload2)  # code hangs here
a.start()
```

But each time I create variable "a", whole program hangs in while loop, which should be running in another thread.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It hangs on *creation* of the thread, before you start it?

Comment: Yes, if I do put `print("test")` before `a.start()`, it isn't printed, so I assume it hangs on creation of the thread.

Comment: How did you find out its blocked ? Is self.xbox.stdout.readline() a blocking call and you are doing something else in main that you don't see being working ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to add print behind it and it doesn't print anything. Also program using this module hangs too.

Comment: That's a *lot* of code to put into `__init__`. I suggest you remove everything except simple variable declarations, and put the rest into an explicitly called `start()` method.

Comment: Alright I did some cleaning and it didn't help. `start()` method needs to be called sooner than subprocess `self.xbox` is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be having issues with your `__init__`. I put it in a simple class as an example, and it runs as expected.

```
import time
from threading import Thread


class InfiniteLooper():

    def __init__(self):
        a = Thread(target=self.reload2) # reload, not reload(), otherwise you're executing reload2 and assigning the result to Target, but it's an infinite loop, so... 
        print('Added thread')
        a.start()
        print('Thread started')

    def reload2(self):
        while True:
            self.response = input('Enter something')
            print('read')
            time.sleep(0.5)


loop = InfiniteLooper()
```

Output:

Added thread
Thread started
Enter something
1
read
Enter something
1
read

As you can see, the "Enter something" appears after I've added the thread and started it. It also loops fine

Comment: I updated my thread and added contents of `__init__` function.

Comment: @Astra3 Your updated code says you're doing `a = Thread(target=self.reload2())`, but your quote after it says `a = Thread(target=self.reload2)`. Any chance you're hanging because you're assigning the function results to target instead of the function itself? The 2nd way is the correct way, the part in your updated code block is not.